# How to use ->append v. protected $appends in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How do you append an attribute to one query but not all of the queries for a model. 
I know you can add attributes to all queries in the model by adding

```
protected $appends = ['icon'];

public function getIconAttribute(){
    return Gravatar::src($this->email, 100).'&r=g&d=mm';
}
```

I want to add it for only one query

```
$usernames = User::where('username', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->get('search').'%')
   ->append('icon')->get();
```

but that gives the error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::append()`

I can see the method but am feeling dumb
https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_append

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `append()` method is part of `Model` rather than the `Builder` so you have to call it for each model.

You could have something like:

```
$usernames = User::where('username', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->get('search') . '%')
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($user) {
        return $user->append('icon');
    });
```

---

**>= Laravel 5.4**

[Higher Order Messaging](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#higher-order-messages) was introduced in 5.4 so you can now do:

```
$usernames = User::where('username', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->get('search') . '%')
    ->get()
    ->map->append('icon');
```

---

**>= Laravel 7.6**

The `append()` method was introduced to Eloquent Collections in 7.6:

```
$usernames = User::where('username', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->get('search') . '%')
    ->get()
    ->append('icon');
```

Comment: I saw this [pull request](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/9798) which made me think you could do it in the query?

Comment: @whoacowboy You got my hopes up then. No, that pull request was the adding of the `append()` method in general.

Comment: That's too bad, but I'm feeling less stupid. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @whoacowboy I just tried making a pull request to get `append` add to the collection but Taylor wouldn't have it.

Comment: Nice, good try. Laravel, an open-source-ish framework. Post a link and I'll +1 it.

Comment: @whoacowboy Yeah, I know what you mean. https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/16200 Cheers, btw :)